# Need help to correct my program Dev C++

Tags: c++

Need help. Wrong output. The value start 2013 till 2017 is same = 4400. I need help how to integrate the program which the output value is different with every year starting from 2013. Need somebody out there, can guide me with the a little touch which can correct the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

main()
{
    int Year;
    int inipop, projpop;
    int growth, sum;

    printf("\n Please enter number of initial population: ");
    scanf("%d",&inipop); 

    printf("\n Please enter the projected of population: ");
    scanf("%d",&projpop);

    printf("\nThe increase Year of Population: \n"); 

    for(Year = 2013; Year <2018; Year++) 
    {
        growth = inipop + projpop;
        printf("%d      %d\n",Year,growth*2);
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

Please enter number of initial population: 2000

Please enter the projected of population: 200

The increase Year of Population:
2013      4400
2014      4400
2015      4400
2016      4400
2017      4400

Comment: As an aside: your problem is that inside your loop you always assign the exact same unchanging expression to growth.  Somewhere you need to take into account the previous value of the population to calculate the next value.

Comment: growth is calculated from adding two numbers that never change in the loop, so of course it prints the same...

Comment: @MadKeithV This is not an aside, but the actual answer to the question :)

Comment: @DanielDaranas - that comment was the second comment I made originally  on Programmers.SE, the first one was explaining how the question was off-topic there :)

Answer (score 2):

Inside your loop, all the calculations are based on the values of `inipop`, `projpop` and constants. As none of these values gets changed in the loop, and the values for other variables are discarded across the loop iterations, it is entirely appropriate that you get the same value over and over again.

As it is unclear to me how your loop is supposed to work, I can't give more concrete guidance, but to get varying values, you need some variable that gets update in the loop and whose value gets used on the next iteration of the loop.